# LoadLibrary() on Windows XP 64 doesn't find DLL in SysWow64 unless it's in the path?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp

This goes with another question I asked where Windows XP x64 puts up message that an x86 application couldn't start because dll not found, but the app actually does start.   But it turns out to get rid of the message you can simply add c:\windows\syswow64 to the path before running the app and the message goes away.  Which means that it didn't automatically search in SysWow64.  Is that a known issue?  What's the best fix?

TIA!!

Comment: 64 bit was still quite experimental in the XP days. Probably not worth wasting time on. Why are you bothering with an OS that's been unsupported for over a decade?

Comment: Is the x86 app GUI or console, and what was the PATH before you edited it?

Comment: I tagged this question "windows-xp", for those who ignore this tag as an unsupported OS.

Comment: @dxiv console app.

Comment: You could try starting/running it from the 32-bit cmd prompt `%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe`. See Microsoft's [Overview of the compatibility considerations for 32-bit programs on 64-bit versions of Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/896456/overview-of-the-compatibility-considerations-for-32-bit-programs-on-64).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be related to console applications as x86 GUI apps run fine.  The answer is to add %SystemRoot%\SysWow64 to the path.